# Event not being fired when installed as Service

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, service, thread-safety

I'm using a plugin which can register whenever or not I plug in a fingerprint reader into the computer. This is being done by events. The event gets triggered and the reader gets added to a List.

When running the application within Visual Studio, everything works fine. The service is being 'started' by instantiating an instance in the WPF UI application.

When I install the service (the WPF UI is disconnected but an instance of the service logic is created and a thread is started), everything works fine. Logs show the initial code with subscribing to the events is being ran. This code looks like this:

```
public GriauleReader()
{
     log.Debug("Loading the GrFingerLib library");
     if (FingerXCtrlClass != null)
     {
         // Subscribe to the plug, unplug and imageAcquired events from the GrFingerXCtrlClass library.
         FingerXCtrlClass.SensorPlug += ReaderPlug;
         FingerXCtrlClass.SensorUnplug += ReaderUnplug;
         FingerXCtrlClass.ImageAcquired += ImageAcquired;

         log.Debug("Successfully registered for the events sent by a Griaule fingerprint reader.");
     }
}
```

As I said before, this works when running from Visual Studio. When installed as a service, the above code gets executed as well. Unfortunately, `ReaderPlug` only gets called when running the application in Visual Studio (WPF instance).

```
public override void ReaderPlug(string readerId)
{

    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

    if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(readerId)))
    {
        if (!readerId.Equals("File"))
        {
            log.Debug("Reader pluggedin event of GriauleReader is received and start processing...");

            // Send an event to the FingerprintReaderLogic to notify that there is new reader plugged in.
            DispatchReaderPluggedInEvent(readerId, GetFingerprintReaderType());
        }
    }
    else
    {
        log.Error(
                "No reader id is received. Plugin event has no reader id. Plugged reader cannot be added to the system.");
    }
}
```

I myself think that something is going wrong because of threading. Perhaps the original thread is being killed or something like that. What could possibly be the cause of the described problem, and is there a way to check if certain Threads are or are not alive?

Comment: Isn't it a problem of user account? Have you tried to attach debugger to a running service http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.100).aspx ?

Comment: Yes I have, that's why I know the events aren't being called.....